# Best way to use Orgs in Trello

Tags: trello

I have been given the go ahead to test Trello for our company (Squeee!). I use Trello quite a bit personally but have never touched the Org Feature. What I would like to know is, should I create one organisation called "Company" or should I create many orgs on a per team basis, eg ("Company Core Team")

Is it better for access control to have more of the latter than the former?

Comment: If you put everyone in an org, you can put your boards in the org and enable the "Allow organization members to add themselves to this board" feature on your boards.  Then folks can join whichever boards they need to be part of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using multiple organisation means you will be separating members between organizations. Sounds like it will get messy trying to assign owners while at the same time not double-counting across organizations.

Using one organization and different boards based on projects instead of teams could be an approach to use. If there is a case in which one team always ends up doing the same types of projects then they are naturally assigned to it. Otherwise, where there is a manager that oversee more than one project/team, you will be able to add to multiple boards.

The moment you know that there will be a large amount of crossover between teams should indicate when you should use one organisation.

In terms of whether too many boards will fill the main organization area, you can use the "Visibility: Who can see the board" to adjust that. Thus team members only see what projects they are a part of.